# Looking for an elementary solution of this limit

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits

I was collecting some exercises for my students, and I found this one in a book: compute, if it exists, the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \int_x^{2x} \sin \left( \frac{1}{t} \right) \, dt.
$$
It seems to me that this limit exists by monotonicity. Moreover, since $\frac{2}{\pi}x \leq \sin x \leq x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$, I could easily show that
$$
\frac{2}{\pi} \log 2 \leq \lim_{x \to +\infty} \int_x^{2x} \sin \left( \frac{1}{t} \right) \, dt \leq \log 2.
$$
WolframAlpha suggests a "closed" form for the integral, and by dominated convergence the limit turns out to be $\log 2$. However, passing to a limit in the $\operatorname{Ci}(\cdot)$ function is not really elementary. I wonder if there is a simpler approach that a student can understand at the end of a first course in mathematical analysis.

Comment: Given $0<\delta<1$, for $t$ sufficiently large, $\sin(1/t)\ge (1-\delta)/t$.

Comment: Substituting $u = 1/t$ and using $u - u^3/6 < \sin u < u$ for $0 < u < 1$ looks elementary to me.

Comment: @Siminore: Sorry for asking a basic question but what is the hint for sinx $\leq$ x? Do you use the expansion of sine function?

Comment: I take this for granted with my students. I suggest looking at the graphs. For a rigorous proof, you can indeed expand.

Comment: When $x \to \infty$, just replace $\sin\left(1/t\right)$ by $1/t$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrate by parts, with $u=\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ and $dv=dt$.  We get that this is equal to

$$
\left[t\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|_x^{2x}+\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt
$$

Now the first term equals

$$
\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2x}\right)}{\frac{1}{2x}}-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}
$$

which limits to zero.  On the second term, for sufficiently large $t$, $1-\varepsilon\leq\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\leq 1$.  So we get that the second term is between $(1-\varepsilon)\log2$ and $\log2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{x}^{2x}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt}=\int_{x}^{2x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\cdot t^{-(2n+1)}\,dt= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!} \int_{x}^{2x}{t^{-(2n+1)} dt}$$

Since 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \int_{x}^{2x}{t^{-(2n+1)}dt}=\begin{cases}0,& n >0
\\ \log2,& n=0\end{cases} $$

We conclude that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \int_{x}^{2x}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt}= \log2.$$

Comment: Yes, I had devised this proof, but I should prove that the series and the integral can be swapped. This is not taught in a first course in analysis.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_x^{2x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t} \right)\,dt=\int_{\frac{1}{2x}}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\sin(u)}{u^2}\,du,
$$
$$
\sin(u)=u+o(1)u,
$$
if $u$ is around $0$,
(here we use the elemetary $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1$) 
so
$$
\int_{\frac{1}{2x}}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\sin(u)}{u^2}\,du=\int_{\frac{1}{2x}}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{u}(1+o(1))\,du,
$$
where $o(1)\to 0$ as $u\to0$, which is the case, because $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{x}^{2x}\sin\pars{1 \over t}\,\dd t&=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{1/x}^{1/2x}\sin\pars{t}\,\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
=\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{1/x}^{1/2x}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\braces{%
-\bracks{-\int_{1/x}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t}
+
\bracks{-\int_{1/2x}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{-{\rm ci}\pars{1 \over x} + {\rm ci}\pars{1 \over 2x}}
\end{align}
where ${\rm ci}\pars{z}$ is the $\it\mbox{Cosine Integral}$ which satisfies
$\lim_{z \to 0}\bracks{{\rm ci}\pars{z} - \gamma - \ln\pars{z}} = 0$. $\gamma$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni constant*. Then,

> \begin{align}
> &\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{x}^{2x}\sin\pars{1 \over t}\,\dd t=
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\braces{%
> -\bracks{{\rm ci}\pars{1 \over x} - \gamma - \ln\pars{1 \over x}}
> +\bracks{{\rm ci}\pars{1 \over 2x} - \gamma - \ln\pars{1 \over 2x}} + \ln\pars{2}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{x}^{2x}\sin\pars{1 \over t}\,\dd t = \ln\pars{2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\int_{x}^{2x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{2x}^{4x}\sin\left(\frac{2}{t}\right)\,dt=\int_{2x}^{4x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt<\int_{2x}^{4x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt$$

Answer (score 0):

In the continuation of what Gaffney wrote, Cos[1/t] can be developed for large values of t as

1 - 1/(2 t^2) + 1/(24 t^4) - 1/(720 t^6) + ....

So, the value of Gaffney's last integral between $x$ and $2x$ is

Log[2] - 3/(16 x^2) + 5/(512 x^4) + ...

Answer (score 0):

If $t$ approaches infinity, $sin(1/t)$ will approach $0$, so you can just use the Taylor expansion, which we know to be absolutely convergent (if the students have had Taylor series in their first analysis course):

$$ \begin{align*}& lim_{x\to\infty} \int_x^{2x} sin(1/t) dx\\
= & lim_{x\to\infty} \int_x^{2x} (1/t) + O((1/t)^3) dx\\
= & lim_{x\to\infty} \left[ln(t) + O((1/t)^2)\right]_x^{2x}\\
= & lim_{x\to\infty} \left[ln(2) + O((1/x)^2)\right]\\
= & log(2)
\end{align*} $$